# Unity Android build Trying to add file "Temp/StagingArea/Data/sharedassets1.assets.resS" which does not exist on disk

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm running Unity3D 5.5.0b9. My Android build completes and creates an APK but I get 24 errors very similar to the ones below. I found a few other posts online but their solutions don't help.

Trying to add file "Temp/StagingArea/Data/f6f48c4c35c3947f98b2e8172e9711a1.assets.resS" which does not exist on disk.
UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()

Trying to add file "Temp/StagingArea/Data/globalgamemanagers.assets.resS" which does not exist on disk.
UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()
Trying to add file "Temp/StagingArea/Data/sharedassets0.assets.resS" which does not exist on disk.
UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()
Trying to add file "Temp/StagingArea/Data/sharedassets1.assets.resS" which does not exist on disk.
UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a well known bug. You can vote for the bug fix [here](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/player-missed-texture-and-shader-on-mesh-generated-from-terrain-asset-file-in-standalone-build).

You are still using beta version of *5.5* (5.5.0b9). I suggest you update to the latest *f* version as it looks like this bug has been [fixed](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/android-after-building-the-project-errors-about-missing-temp-files-appear-in-console) in the latest final release([*5.5.0f3*](https://store.unity.com/download?ref=update)).

Comment: Download 5.5.0f3 from the link I provided in my answer. 5.5.0b9 is a beta version and no longer has updates. You need 5.5.0f3 which is the final release.

Comment: I'll try it. Thanks.

Comment: So file a bug and tell Unity that the fix doesn't work for you. You can also try deleting the Temp folder.